# My line chart is not working properly on javafx please

Tags: netbeans, charts, javafx, linechart, scenebuilder

this is my code which I used for my line chart but for some reason it works but shows a zig zag pattern and doesn't behave like a line chart.

am I doing anything wrong here? my data is linked to my web server

private void constructLineChart() {
        LineChart1.getData().clear();

```
    for (CheckBox checkBox : Arrays.asList(CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3,CheckBox4, CheckBox5, CheckBox6,CheckBox7, CheckBox8, CheckBox9)) {
        if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
            XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
            series.setName(checkBox.getText());

            for (Sales sale : sales) {
                if (sale.getVehicle().equals(checkBox.getText()))

                {

                    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(sale.getQTR(), sale.getQuantity()));
                }         
            }

                  for (Sales sale : sales) {
                if (sale.getYear().equals(checkBox.getText()))


                {

                    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(sale.getQTR(), sale.getQuantity()));
                }         
            }
                  for (Sales sale : sales) {
                if (sale.getRegion().equals(checkBox.getText()))

                {
             series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(sale.getQTR(), sale.getQuantity()));
                }         
            }

            LineChart1.getData().add(series);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your end goal is but I'll take a guess at your problem.

If you are trying to create a separate line for each of your different categories (vehicle, year, region) then you should have a separate series for each of those.

```
    XYChart.Series vehicleSeries = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series yearSeries = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series regionSeries = new XYChart.Series();
```

Then you would update a given series based on which type of sale you are evaluating.

```
vehicleSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(sale.getQTR(), sale.getQuantity()));
```

Finally you would add all of these series to the linechart.

```
lineChart1.getData().addAll(vehicleSeries, yearSeries, regionSeries);
```